# nginx assets in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, assets

I was wondering if there is a better way to define assets path in nginx. For example, I want nginx to serve assets in subfolders. For now, I use this technique which does not look very dry to me.

```
location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}

location ^~ /assets/downloads {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Could you suggest something better for folders inside assets folder? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your config is almost right (for what you're trying to achieve). Since I don't have the full config, I'll guess a solution:

```
location ^~ /assets/ {
    alias /absolute/path/to/assets/;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Notice the `alias` directive (as well as the trailing slash on the absolute path). This tells NGINX to take the URI and recurse the assets directory (searching within subfolders). It's similar to using `root` and `try_files` when serving content. For differences between `root` and `alias`, see this [link](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,129656,130107).

Comment: Thank you. I tested it on my rails app and it worked! That's what I was looking for exactly. Accepted your answer. Have a good day.